# Close my program before Windows shutdown

Tags: c++, dev-c++

I´m making a program that must save its files without user interaction when the computer is being turned off.  I tried, but I cannot understand how to do it, because most of the info I found is for C#.  I found the [`SystemEvents::SessionEnding`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.sessionending.aspx) event using the below code for C++, but I don´t know how to implement this in dev-c++:

```
public:
    event SessionEndingEventHandler^ SessionEnding {
        static void add(SessionEndingEventHandler^ value);
        static void remove(SessionEndingEventHandler^ value);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not c++. This is c++/cli, which is a language  targeting .Net. You need to find how to do it using Windows API.

Answer (score 4):

The code you showed is not C++.  It is C++/CLI, aka C++ w/ .NET managed extensions.  It only works in Visual Studio.

The plain C/C++ way to do what you are looking for is to:

1. use a window procedure in a GUI project to handle [`WM_QUERYENDSESSION`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376890.aspx) and [`WM_ENDSESSION`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376889.aspx) window messages.
2. use [`SetConsoleCtrlHandler()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686016.aspx) in a console project to handle `CTRL_LOGOFF_EVENT` and `CTRL_SHUTDOWN_EVENT` notifications.
3. use [`RegisterServiceCtrlHandlerEx()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685058.aspx) in a service project to handle `SERVICE_CONTROL_PRESHUTDOWN` and `SERVICE_CONTROL_SHUTDOWN` notifications.

Refer to MSDN for details:

[Logging Off](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376876.aspx)

[Shutting Down](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376881.aspx)

Comment: Thanks a lot, you´ve oriented me, effectively my application is in a console, so I used setConsoleCtrlHandler to add my HandlerRoutine, wich one works with CTRL_SHUTDOWN_EVENT to detect when Windows is being turned off.